# How do I make my email alert *annoying*?

Tags: email, alerts

I'm on call a lot and need to know when I get an email. The little dings and dongs available as alert tones don't cut it - I might be asleep, or in the shower, or whatever. I need it to be persistent, annoying, loud, and not shut up until I acknowledge that I heard it. Unfortunately, this seems to be difficult.

I found an app in the store that claims to do it, but it only supports POP - I need Exchange. I'd rather something that hooked into existing notifications so I could use the normal mail client, but that seems to be impossible.

I can't be the only one with this need - does anyone know of a good solution?

Thanks

Comment: Adding onto this question, is there something that would allow for annoying alerts for one specific email sender? I sometimes receive from a senders around 4-5am and need to wake up. Obviously one that bugged me for *all* emails would be useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's [Missed Message Flasher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tomatox.missedmessageflasher) in the Play Market.

Note: I haven't actually tried the app.

Comment: Oh my god, this works perfectly. I don't know how I missed this, I tried a few similar apps with no success.

Thank you kindly.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a limit on how long a ringtone can be? If not, you can select a loud and annoying ringtone, create a sound file that contains this ringtone in a long loop and use that file as a ring tone. One caveat is that I don't think you can't abort a notification sound.

Comment: I don't know about notifications, but alarm tones are limited to 10 minutes before they auto-silence. The concern I'd have for just making the notification sound longer is you might not be able to abort it when you acknowledge it...

Comment: @fluffy I think you can turn it off by opening the notifications area. And maybe as for phone calls, press the volume down button.